# @Mock values isn't refelected on @injectMock Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and I was trying to write the unit test for nstead adapters
lets say we have
I have 3 classes and the last one will update a map to me, return it to the middle then return it again to final layer

```
List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x
Class A {
    Public void method1(List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x) {
                    method2(x)
    }
    private void method2 (List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x) {
                    x.add(...)
    }
}

Class B {
     A a;
    Public int methodB(List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x) {
                    a.method1(x)
                    return x.length;
    }
}

Class C {
     B b;
    Public void methodC(List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x) {
                    int size = b.methodB(x)
    }
}
```

Now when I wanted to write a unit test for class C, I did this

```
Public Class cTest {

List<Map<Integer, List<String>> x;
@InjectMocks
C c;

@Mock
B b;

@Test
Public Void test() {

   when(b.methodB(x)).thenReturn(1);
      c.methodC(x)
    }
}
```

The thing is when I debug the call for c.methodC(x) in unit test and I check the x it will always be empty
So how can I fill it in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public Class cTest {
```

Needs to have the Mockito extension declared:

```java
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class })
class cTest {
```

You'll need the extension on your classpath. If using maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

References: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension